# GetStream.com question: how can a user that posted something delete/edit his post

Tags: getstream-io

Following GetStream.com documentation, I implemented an example react native app.
Is there a way to delete or update posts? From the `StatusUpdateForm` component or from the platform dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating posts (activities) are only supported server side so it can't be done by a client directly.

Deleting posts is supported by client side auth. However, support in the library isn't there though. [Created a ticket for it](https://github.com/GetStream/react-native-activity-feed/issues/130).

Comment: Thank you @ferhatelmas